# FreqDist with NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

The Python package `nltk` has the [FreqDist](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.probability.html#nltk.probability.FreqDist) function which gives you the frequency of words within a text. I am trying to pass my text as an argument but the result is of the form:

```
[' ', 'e', 'a', 'o', 'n', 'i', 't', 'r', 's', 'l', 'd', 'h', 'c', 'y', 'b', 'u', 'g', '\n', 'm', 'p', 'w', 'f', ',', 'v', '.', "'", 'k', 'B', '"', 'M', 'H', '9', 'C', '-', 'N', 'S', '1', 'A', 'G', 'P', 'T', 'W', '[', ']', '(', ')', '0', '7', 'E', 'J', 'O', 'R', 'j', 'x']
```

whereas in the example on the `nltk` website, the result was whole words not characters. Here is how I am currently using the function:

```py
file_y = open(fileurl)
p = file_y.read()
fdist = FreqDist(p)
vocab = fdist.keys()
vocab[:100]
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please add a link to the example.

Comment: NB, better Python idiom is: `with open(fileurl) as file_y: ...` or `for line in open(file url):`

Answer (score 51):

`FreqDist` expects an iterable of tokens. A string is iterable --- the iterator yields every character.

Pass your text to a tokenizer first, and pass the tokens to `FreqDist`.

Comment: Indeed it does, but its docstring doesn't say that *anywhere*, nor do its error messages, and it would be trivial for its `__init__()` to either raise an error message saying so on non-iterator input, or accept a sequence and convert it to an iterator.

Comment: @afg102 If it has worked, please accept the answer so that others also know what is the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 33):

FreqDist runs on an array of tokens. You're sending it a an array of characters (a string) where you should have tokenized the input first:

```
words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(p)
fdist = FreqDist(words)
```

Answer (score 23):

NLTK's `FreqDist` accepts any iterable. As a string is iterated character by character, it is pulling things apart in the way that you're experiencing.

In order to do count words, you need to feed `FreqDist` words. How do you do that? Well, you might think (as others have suggested in the answer to your question) to feed the whole file to `nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize`.

```
>>> # first, let's import the dependencies
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.probability import FreqDist

>>> # wrong :(
>>> words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(p)
>>> fdist = FreqDist(words)
```

`word_tokenize` builds word models from sentences. It needs to be fed each sentence one at a time. It will do a relatively poor job when given whole paragraphs or even documents.

So, what to do? Easy, add in a sentence tokenizer!

```
>>> fdist = FreqDist()
>>> for sentence in nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(p):
...     for word in nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sentence):
>>>         fdist[word] += 1
```

One thing to bear in mind is that there are many ways to tokenize text. The modules `nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize` and `nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize` simply pick a reasonable default for relatively clean, English text. There are several other options to chose from, which you can read about in the [API documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html).

Comment: The OP doesn't want letter frequencies! (noone else does either...) They want word frequencies.

Comment: Actually, letter frequencies are very common features for automatic language detection.

Comment: True, for that niche. Also decryption. In general not much though.

Comment: Really useful answer, however it seems to be a bit outdated: `AttributeError: 'FreqDist' object has no attribute 'inc'`. Not complaining, just throwing it out there for others to be aware of this. I'll try to figure out an answer to this ;) Thanks

Comment: Yes, things have changed quite a bit to some of the internal NLTK APIs in the last 5 years! Will update the code :)

Comment: Hei Tim, you're missing a colon at the end of the second `for` loop statement.

Answer (score 9):

You simply have to use it like this:

```
import nltk
from nltk.probability import FreqDist

sentence='''This is my sentence'''
tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sentence)
fdist=FreqDist(tokens)
```

The variable fdist is of the type "class 'nltk.probability.FreqDist"  and contains the frequency distribution of words.

Answer (score 1):

```
Your_string = "here is my string"
tokens = Your_string.split()
```

Do this way, and then use the **NLTK** functions

**it will give your tokens in words but not in characters**

Answer (score 0):

```
text_dist = nltk.FreqDist(word for word in list(text) if word.isalpha())
top1_text1 = text_dist.max()
maxfreq = top1_text1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.